# Time Stamp on Data from Query

Tags: php, sql

I am using the query

```
INSERT INTO dailyNR SELECT subject, email 
FROM daily WHERE daily.subject NOT IN(SELECT dailyR.subject FROM dailyR WHERE
dailyR.time >= now( ) - INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

It was working great as my Table dailyNR had only two columns. Now I need to add a third column for TIME to record the time/date when the query was run (and the table was populated). How do I add timestamp into this query ? NOW() would be good, but how do I change the syntax for that ?

Will it go something like this: INSERT INTO dailyNR SELECT time,subject, email .................
OR will I have to do it from PHPmyAdmin ?

Answer (score 0):

Either add `now()` to your query

```
INSERT INTO dailyNR 
SELECT subject, email, NOW()
FROM daily WHERE daily.subject NOT IN(SELECT dailyR.subject FROM dailyR WHERE
dailyR.time >= now( ) - INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

or use a default for your new column.

Comment: @user3054737: Consider specifying explicitly the columns you are populating: `INSERT INTO dailyNR (subject, email, time) SELECT ...`. Might spare you some bitter hours in the future.